# twitter request_token 401 unauthorized

Tags: oauth, twitter, appcelerator

ok after two days of tryouts i still cant my titanium application to play well with twitter request_token api 1.1, i am always getting 401 unauthorized error .below is my code. i am blocked so any help is appreciated.

```
var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
                onerror : function(e) {
                    alert(this.status + ":" + e.error);
                },
                onload : function(e) {
                    alert(this.responseText);
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        var resposeText = this.responseText;
                    }

                }
            });
httpClient.open('POST', "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
httpClient.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

var now = new Date().getTime();

var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var nonce = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    nonce += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
}
var parameters = "oauth_callback=" + Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent("http://apicallback.stc.com.sa");

var signature = "POST&" + Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token") + "&" + Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent(parameters);
var header = "OAuth oauth_callback=\"" + Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent("http://apicallback.stc.com.sa") + "\",oauth_consumer_key=\"wPdlchopdYaqHhab8H8jMA\",oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\",oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + now + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
httpClient.setRequestHeader("Authorization", header);
httpClient.send(parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

There were several errors :

- Your nonce seems to be built incorrectly. Generate a string with 32 letters and encode it with Base 64.
- Your signature is not built correctly too. Refer to the [Twitter Developers documentation about making signatures](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature). Here are your errors :

  - All the OAuth arguments are missing but `oauth_callback`. The OAuth arguments which are used in the `Authorize` header have to be included in the parameters for the signature
  - You do not build the key to sign datas.
  - You do not use the signature method (`oauth_signature_method` which is set to "*`HMAC-SHA1`*") to sign your datas.
- Your timestamp is too big. It is the number of **seconds** since the Unix Epoch time, not the milliseconds. Add a "`/1000`" :

  `var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000`

More generally have a look at Twitter Developers documentation about authorizing requests : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

Comment: you are right, i was missing out couple of stuff. i went over oauth docs (http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step2) to get things in order.thanks

Answer (score 0):

by chance i found javascript library posted in twitter list of libraries. check it out [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth/downloads). there is also [API doc](http://bytespider.github.com/jsOAuth/api-reference/) for the library :). now i am able to get the authorization token but when i perform search by posting to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json i get 401 (unauthorized) error. now i am stuck again. any idea what might be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple twitter libraries out there for appcelerator that already work, I would suggest starting with one of them.

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/33810421717/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-posting-images-to-twitter-with-social_plus-js

see link to github repo at bottom of posting

Comment: thanks, i eded up using jsOAuth (https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth/downloads)